# Upgrade Opencart 1.5.x to 2.2.x

Tags: opencart, upgrade

I have a old version opencart made in 1.5.6.4 version of opencart, I wanted the latest version of opencart, 
I tried to follow the documentation given by opencart upgrade instructions but when I tried that, I followed many errors and unable to login to admin page so many undefined errors appear on the site.
Is there any safe way to upgrade the opencart website without having any errors and losing data?

Comment: I found the solutions to upgrade opencart to latest version opencart

Comment: can you share the solutions? I am facing the same problems

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to say how to upgrade opencart to latest version because opencart released new version opencart 2.2.0.0 where many bugs have fixed and is complete new features and also comes with different appearance and responsive in nature, so it would be good idea to upgrade to latest opencart. But the problem is : if you do not have good knowledge of PHP, you will face lots of errors and challenges. So it is always advisable to hire a PHP developer for upgrading your opencart 1.5.x to 2.2.x latest , you can find this post useful which describes why and how you should upgrade your opencart 
http://templatecinderella.com/upgrade-opencart-1-5-x-to-opencart-2-2-x-version.html